# How exactly does V8 optimize/inline?

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-chrome, inline, v8

I'm wondering whether it is possible to get knowledge of how exactly V8 optimizes and inlines things.

I created three simple [test functions](http://jsperf.com/optimizing-v8) which all calculate the sine of a angle in degrees. I put them all into closures so that V8 should be able to inline the local variables.

---

1. Using a precalculated constant `Math.PI / 180`, and then do `Math.sin(x * constant)`.

I used this code:

```
var test1 = (function() {
  var constant = Math.PI / 180; // only calculate the constant once

  return function(x) {
    return Math.sin(x * constant);
  };
})();
```

---

2. Calculating the constant on the fly.

```
var test2 = (function() {
  var pi = Math.PI; // so that the compiler knows pi cannot change
                    // and it can inline it (Math.PI could change
                    // at any time, but pi cannot)

  return function(x) {
    return Math.sin(x * pi / 180);
  };
})();
```

---

3. Using literal numbers and calculating the constant on the fly.

```
var test3 = (function() {
  return function(x) {
    return Math.sin(x * 3.141592653589793 / 180);
  };
})();
```

---

Suprisingly, the results were as follows:

```
test1 - 25,090,305 ops/sec
test2 - 16,919,787 ops/sec
test3 - 16,919,787 ops/sec
```

It looks like `pi` did get inlined in `test2` as `test2` and `test3` result in exactly the same amount of operations per second.

On the other hand, the division does not seem to be optimized (i.e. precalculated), since `test1` is significantly faster.

- Why is the constant not precalculated if you don't do so manually in this case?
- Is it possible to see how V8 exactly optimizes functions on a certain webpage?

Comment: I'm not sure if the concept of C style inlining caries over to JITed virtual machines.  I'm just speculating, but I suspect that V8 applies run time optimization to functions that are frequently called, but it is probably hard to predict.

Comment: @mikerobi: This may be a naive question - but wouldn't it be possible to simply see what V8 is doing during compiling/optimizing/inlining, like some kind of debugging tool?

Comment: It is probably possible, but I doubt anyone outside the V8 development team could tell you how.

Comment: Well, PyPy's JIT for instance has extensive logging and they started building a tool to view all the intermediate representations the code went through (Python bytecode, JIT IR, machine code), so such things should be possible in theory. But I guess it's made easier by the facts that (1) the actual JIT is machine-generated and (2) it's a tracing JIT.

Comment: V8 does _not_ perform constant propagation at the moment. Also you penalize V8 by creating functions in the loop (setup is called multiple times): try the modified test case http://jsperf.com/optimizing-v8/2 instead. It removes overhead introduced by multiple reoptimizations of new born instances of closures and makes the picture more clear.

Comment: Though it's now completely unclear to me why the last case is so much faster on jsperf. It really should not be. The only difference between it and the other two is additional context lookup in `test1` and `test2` which is nowhere as expensive.

Comment: `I doubt anyone outside the V8 development team could tell you how` --  How so? the code is open: http://v8.googlecode.com/svn

Comment: @Vyacheslav Egorov: Woops, that makes for a great difference indeed. Thanks for pointing that out! On the other hand, it also makes for more questions... This all seems a mysterious thing.

Comment: I vaguely remember some acquaintance who's working on crankshaft showing me the compiled code that it produces some time ago. Don't ask me about details, but I think if you compile it yourself you can tell it to create a developer shell that can be coerced to produce that stuff - a quick grep through the source rep should help there. Obviously anyone working on a compiler HAS to see the produced code, otherwise you'll have a hard time working on it imo..

Comment: @sehe, you have access to the source code, but have not proven you can answer the question.  If you spent enough time digging through the sources you might be able to answer the question, but how many people currently have the necessary knowledge to answer the question?  The OP wasn't looking for a research project, he wants the results of the research.

Comment: @mikerobi What are you talking about? The V8 code is well documented, and people are using it and changing it in tons of ways, from Node.js to what have you. You wrote a BS "who knows, it's too difficult" comment, that doesn't mean you have to defend it. Here's an example: http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/09/23/grokking-v8-closures-for-fun.html

Answer (score 7):

An educated guess at your first question:

Strictly speaking, it can't constant-fold the `pi / 180` part, because you don't do `pi / 180` in the second and third function. You just divide `(x * pi)` by `180` (the multiplication has precedence).

Now, you may be asking why it doesn't change the order of operations to wind up with something it can optimize (this process is called reassociation, by the way)... after all, the result is equivalent (`a * b / c = (a * b) / c`). Math says so, right?

Well, math says so, but math doesn't use floating point numbers. With floats, things are more complicated. `x * pi` may be rounded, and then the reordering would lead to a different result. The errors will probably be tiny, but still, the leading rule of compiler optimization is: Thou must not change the program's outcome. It's better to perform suboptimal on a few math benchmarks written in an unfortunate way than being off by a pixel (yes, that may be noticeable) in some graphics code.

Comment: Side note in case someone doubts my claim that the functions will give different results: Try it with `x = 0.6784993546113602`, for instance. I found this and many other numbers with `Math.random()`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting. It makes for some more research (like with a constant `(a * b) * x`).

Comment: Using `pi * 180 * x` does indeed cause different results to be generated - now `test1` and `test3` are equal but `test2` has become slower. I think this can be explained with operator precendece. I'm going to try to search for a reason for `pi` in `test2` not to be inlined anymore. http://jsperf.com/optimizing-v8-2

Comment: in that case, what does `x * (pi / 180)` give?  The compiler could theoretically pull the `pi / 180` out now.

Comment: @cwolves: When I compare my initial test and the same one with parentheses added, there seems to be little to no improvement: http://jsperf.com/optimizing-v8/2 and http://jsperf.com/optimizing-v8/3. That would mean the floating point/operator precedence idea is actually *not* applicable. Mysterious...

Answer (score 4):

To answer your second question, you can see the bytecode that V8 optimized your JS to using this tool: http://mrale.ph/irhydra/2/ . It's fantastic for low-level tuning of code in Chrome.